# Mac App Store Sandboxing issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox

I am trying to submit a mac app to the Mac App Store, but it keeps being regected because they say that it not properly sandboxed. They say the app has the entitlement : 'com.apple.developer.maps'.

I've checked and the entitlements file for the app doesn't have the 'com.apple.developer.maps', nor is the Maps capability enabled in Xcode.
I remember that I have previously used the Maps capability before for the app, but removed it afterward using the toggle in the Xcode Capabilities tab.

Any idea how to fix this thing?

I've tried to check the entitlements using :

```
codesign -d --entitlements - MyApp.app
```

And the output is:

```
Executable=/Users/mppl/Desktop/FT.app/Contents/MacOS/Fast Translate
??qq/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Just a guess: are you by chance still linking against MapKit (use `otool -L` on your binary) and therefore Apple's automated scanning is saying you *need* the maps entitlement? If so remove it from your project and try again.

Comment: If it's not what CRD said then contact Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Their engineers will double-check the (non-engineer) review.